# How to get last modified date of file in Laravel, NOT converted to UTC

Tags: php, laravel

I'm, trying to get the last modified date of a file in Laravel. Works fine, except that the File::lastModified() function is returning the Unix timestamp according to UTC. So, looking in Windows Explorer, I see the "Date Modified" for the file is "4/11/2018 10:32 AM". If I execute the code below, what echoes out is "2018-04-11 14:32:12", which is off by +4 hours:

```
$lastmodified = File::lastModified($filename);
$lastmodified = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $lastmodified);
$lastmodified = $lastmodified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $lastmodified;
```

So along the line it's looking at the 10:32 AM time, converting that to UTC, and then returning the Unix timestamp. Isn't there some way to get a timestamp without the 10:32 AM time ever being converted to UTC?

Comment: For the record, timestamps don't have timezones, not in the general sense at least, they're the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 in UTC time. With that said, you can offset that with your current timezone fairly easily, something like `$current_timezone = $timestamp + date('Z');`. This assumes you have the correct timezone set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unix timestamp will always be in UTC.  You can use [DateTime::setTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to convert the time to your desired timezone.

```
$lastmodified = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $lastmodified);
$lastmodified->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

Comment: So it's converting the time it sees, 10:32 AM, then I have to tell it to convert back, specifying a timezone. Problem is, that timezone could change (like EST to EDT or EDT to EST). Isn't there a function that will just return the exact "last modified" datetime without any conversions?

Comment: Most systems, especially Linux and Unix (maybe Windows too), don't store modification times with a timezone.  This would be incredibly hard to maintain if you change timezones.   Almost all systems should and do use UTC for all historical records.

Comment: What he said. Timestamps is about as much precision and timezone independence as you can get without using an atomic clock.

Comment: Let me ask instead - where/how in Laravel's config do you set the app's timezone globally? I'm looking in the config file, and I figure one of those files must be where I can add something like "['app.timezone' => 'America/New York']".

Comment: That's not going to change anything because the function returns a unix timestamp.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration

Comment: Okay, so I set the timezone on config/app.php, in the timezone section. I also created an environment variable on .env:(APP_TIMEZONE=America/New_York). Then I used your suggestion above: $lastmodified->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(env('APP_TIMEZONE'))); and it's returning the correct local time.
Another reason I prefer using ColdFusion. Using the cfdirectory tag, I get a query object that contains basically everything you'd see in Windows Explorer for a given folder. Including the last modified date, as is.

Comment: I wouldn't use env() in your code since it doesn't work once the config is cached, which is common in production.  Only use env() in config files and use the config() helper within your code.